# How can I respec my badass rank bonus stats?

Tags: borderlands-2

So the **bonus stats** you get for your **badass rank** is shared and accumulated amongst all your characters.  So each character has their own level and stats while your **badass rank** is like *your* level (as a player) and your the stats you gain are given to all your characters.

This is great and I love the idea but I accidentally used up one of my **badass tokens** on a stat I didn't want.

**Is it possible to respec my badass rank bonus points so I can use my badass tokens on abilities that I *do* want?  How can I do it?**

Just to be clear, I don't necessarily want to be able to use all my tokens on one single stat, I just want to be refunded all my tokens so I can start building up my stats again.  And that includes being limited to choosing 1 of 5 (random?) stats per token.

Comment: There are lots of ways to earn more easily. Create a new character and do the challenges again. Or new character and try trading (just going to the trading menu, don't have to actually trade) 50 times with someone. Then buy ranks, delete character, create new one, repeat. You shouldn't need to respec. See http://venturebeat.com/2012/09/17/breaking-borderlands-2-easy-money-xp-eridium-boss-fights-and-tokens/#post-532853 for a guide for similar tricks.

Comment: fwiw, my badass ranks got deallocated when I purchased the mechromancer pack, this is probably a 1 time thing though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is NO, you can't. There is no feature to reset them.

Also i did check and it seems those stats are stored on remote servers and not your local machine, so we can't just tweak a file either. (As best as i could find.)

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I just hope they don't make this a DLC thing or otherwise make us pay to be able to do this.

Comment: I don't see why there's any need to do so *at all*. You can gain an endless number of Badass Ranks/Tokens, and none of the stats you can choose are *negative*, so why bother?

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh: Well at lower ranks you can earn tokens at lower rates than you can at higher ranks.  So the stat I could have had after earning 200 badass points will cost 50000 badass points for example.

Comment: @Draken I have Borderlands 2 blocked by my firewall for... various reasons, and still have badass ranks and bonuses show up. This means there is at least a local copy, and possibly they aren't stored elsewhere at all.

Comment: They aren't stored online. They're stored in profile.bin(on the PC, anyways).

Comment: "*it seems those stats are stored on remote servers and not your local machine*" Anyone got a source corroborating this?

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh there are some negative impacts in some builds, for example in fire rate and hyperion "accuracy increases the longer you hold the trigger" weapons

Answer (score 11):

I emailed Gearbox support with the same question outlining the issues and they responded within 3 hours and reset all badass points. Super easy and no hassles. Good luck!

(My previous post was deleted, but I wanted to respond with a new and improved answer.)

Comment: The question is asking how to *respec* their current Badass ranks.  Not reset them back to zero, and have to re-earn all of them.

Comment: Mine were not deleted, they were unapplied now I can apply them where I want. They cycle through with the least used at the top, so it's tricky, but it works. The bars that show your progress with each challenge remain the same though. (This was for PC version)

Comment: Yuck, so we have to go through gearbox just to reset the stats?  That sucks.  Though they really can change anything about the game or its settings so I can't really accept this as an answer.  So if I really wanted to repsec, I'd contact support.  Otherwise it's not possible through normal means.

Answer (score 7):

Actually the bonus stats are saved locally in your profile.bin file, well for PC at least. If you delete that it will remove all your points etc. I can't find anything on the game about the player that is stored on a server. There is no way though to modify the file at the moment.

Comment: I'd be more afraid of losing other progress that is saved in that file. While it may store the bonus stats there, it may hold other important things (such as bank inventory) that I wouldn't want to just toss away.

Comment: I fear the information in this file is synced with the cloud.

Comment: I've deleted the profile.bin then selected my lvl.6 character and reloaded the latest save, now I have no bonus stats at all and 10 badass tokens.

Comment: Deleting your profile.bin would also reset your golden keys. Only do this if you either have no golden keys or are willing to cheat them back in.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to respec badass stats within the game itself.

Badass stats, golden keys, and skins are stored in profile.bin, located in

`C:\Users\[PC user name]\Documents\My Games\Borderlands 2\WillowGame\SaveData\7656119[Steam ID]`.

The "**[Borderlands 2 - Profile Editor](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/borderlands-2-profile-editor.916868/)**" lets one modify these data.

[image: Borderlands 2 - Profile Editor screenshot]

I have used it myself and confirm its functionality. Here are results for virus checks of the two files: [Borderlands 2 - Profile Editor.exe](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/3932d4380b177fa088fdcf78b103283815ca4b5cefdfa62b4047fe69c854fcc6/analysis/) and [LZO.dll](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/ee3b869b668abec332d07c66d1a39f6dbf3a598cc1325b57a0504f8d24ac2e28/analysis/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish would be possible, regardless of whether you could reset your badass rank.

The stat choices appear to be randomly selected with a weight toward the stats that have lower bonuses, so eventually you'll wind up with a list of nothing but "bad" stats, forcing you to choose one.

Comment: If however, you prioritise a 'top 10' of stats that you will spend on at least one of them must show up for every Badass Token

Answer (score -1):

To add to what others have put:

The 5 badass rank choices will almost always be your 5 lowest ranks. so you can only pick 4 you don't want to upgrade and the others will upgrade (roughly) equally

EG.

Max health 0%,
Shield capacity 0%,
Shield recharge delay 0%,
Shield recharge rate 0%,
Everything else 2.2%

You will (nearly) always get to choose from.
Max health,
Shield capacity,
Shield recharge delay,
Shield recharge rate,
and one random bonus from the rest.

Comment: Nope, it's random.  This is just selection bias on your part.  It just _looks_ like the RNG is picking your low stats.

Comment: @MBraedley : it's possible that there's some biasing towards the low levels ... as I think I've only ever taken the melee damage one once, and the last 3 or 4 times I've leveled it up, it's been in there multiple times (3 of the 5 choices, always the bottom three choices.  I'm not sure what my badass rank is, but I have around 12-13% bonuses in everything *except* melee (which us under 2%)

Comment: @Joe Then proof supporting the claim is required.

Comment: @MBraedley : that's not how evidence works ... I can provide proof that it's *not* your 5 lowest ranks, as I have one appear three times, so it's more like my 3 three lowest ... and I really do believe that it's being handled differently now.  (I don't know when it started ... I had taken some time off from playing, and was playing ~2 weeks ago when all of this happened)

Comment: @Joe You're missing my point.  Extraordinary claims, like the one being made in this answer, need extraordinary evidence, which is not provided.  Well it's not really extraordinary, but close enough.  Was the experiment run thousands of times, with all the results recorded?  Probably not.  The assumption going in is that it's random with _maybe_ a little bias to less selected perks.  But this answer doesn't provide evidence one way or another as to whether that assumption is correct.

Comment: @MBraedley : you're trying to make it sound like it's a scientific experiment ... but you seem to be missing my point about a null hypothesis.  You don't need thousands of runs -- you just need one to disprove it.  And I have, it's not the lowest 5, because in my case, one of 'em was repeated 3 times.  (but that one is significantly lower than all of my other bonuses)

Comment: @MBraedley : and after running some tests, 6 of my last 7 baddass turnins ... my two lowest showed up (grende damage at 0% and melee damage at 1%), and my highest showed up 3 times (max health now at 16.8%, when all of the rest of mine are near 12.8%).  So nope, not the lowest 5 items.  The other time was the two lowest, the highest twice, and one other.  Looking at other forums, people are reporting that Max Health comes up often.

Answer (score -1):

just delete bin file, then re-login with you character. It will reset badass rank.

Comment: That sounds like you're just deleting them... not allowing you to re-spec...

Answer (score -2):

You can reset the badass tokens simple. Go into your save game folder and find the file profile.bin and delete this file. Then load borderlands 2 up once and close out then load it up again. select the character that you want to use and then you have your tokens back.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of Fythios's answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85293/26052